# Converting an Object to Address

Tags: java, xml, dbunit

I'm using DBUnit to export to XML. When it writes my Address object, this is what appears in the XML file:

```
<![CDATA[rO0ABXNyABRjc2hlZXRzLmNvcmUuQWRkcmVzc/DHvyOozrwhAgACSQAGY29sdW1uSQADcm93eHAA
AAAAAAAAAA==]]>
```

Now I'm trying to read that, and convert it back to Address, but it isn't working :/

The Address class contain an int Row, int Column.

Anybody know how I can convert this?

Comment: I doubt DBUnit exports stuff which it can't read back... The solution certainly lies in DBUnit itself. All that can be said here is that it looks like base64

Comment: That's binary data (with some embedded ASCII characters) encoded in base64.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following can be used to load back the object from the string in the `CDATA` section (between `<![CDATA[` and  `]]>`):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding; // guava 14
import sheets.core.Address; // your class

class Decode {
   static <T> T decode(String encoded) throws Exception {
      byte[] serialized = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(encoded);
      try (
            ByteArrayInputStream serstr = new ByteArrayInputStream(serialized);
            ObjectInputStream objstr = new ObjectInputStream(serstr);) {
         return (T) objstr.readObject();
      }
   }

   static void example() {
       String encoded = "rO0ABXNy... [snipped] ..."; // load from xml element here.
       Address a = decode(encoded); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decoding this with saxon:base64Binary-to-octets() shows that it is the base64 representation of the octet sequence

```
172 237 0 5 115 114 0 20 99 115 104 101 101 116 115 46 99 111 114 101 46 65 100 100 114 101 115 115 240 199 191 35 168 206 188 33 2 0 2 73 0 6 99 111 108 117 109 110 73 0 3 114 111 119 120 112 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But quite what that sequence of octets means is anyone's guess...